# Fedora Linux - Xresources setting of Xft.dpi is ignored

Tags: authentication, x11, fedora, dpi, gdm

I would like to change the `Xft.dpi` Xresources property (to get larger fonts in LibreOffice).  By default it is 96, as shown by

```
% xrdb -query | grep dpi
Xft.dpi:    96
```

I want to set it to 192 so I created a file `~/.Xresources` with content

```
Xft.dpi:    192
```

I can manually load this with `xrdb -merge`:

```
% xrdb -merge .Xresources
% xrdb -query | grep dpi
Xft.dpi:    192
```

For good measure I also created a `.xinitrc` file which runs the `xrdb -merge` command.  I can see that this does work for other properties; as a test I added `XTerm*background: black`, and that is set correctly at login.

But the dpi setting, no matter what I do, gets stuck at 96, as shown by running xrdb -query from a terminal immediately after login:

```
% xrdb -query | grep dpi
Xft.dpi:    96
```

(The `XTerm*background` setting is shown by `xrdb -query`, so clearly *some* properties are getting set, but somehow not this one.)

I do not see it taking effect in LibreOffice either (while it does do so if set with xrdb after login).  Is something overwriting it back again?

I even edited the global `/etc/X11/Xresources`, changing the dpi from its default 96 to 192, but it still gets stuck at 96 on login.  What is causing it to ignore or override what I have specified in `.Xresources`?

This is Fedora 23 x86_64.

Comment: "but it still gets stuck at 96" How do you know?

Comment: By running xrdb -query.  I have clarified the question to make this clear.  If you use Fedora, I would be interested to see if you can reproduce this.

Comment: Got it. Try setting the dpi in xorg itself and also in fontconfig.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you want to post this suggestion as an answer?  I don't have the machine to hand at the moment but will try it as soon as I get back.  Note that I have set the font size to double using the GNOME control panel, so most applications do appear with bigger fonts, but LibreOffice requires the Xresources property.

Comment: Please try it first, I can't test it right now either.